# Lebesgue points and essentially bounded functions

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory

Let us consider an essentially bounded function $f:[0,1]\to \mathbb{R}^d$, that is $f \in L^{\infty}([0,1],\mathbb{R}^d)$. Let us assume that $f(x) \in A$ for almost every $x\in [0,1]$, where the set $A\subset \mathbb{R}^d$ is compact.

I try to prove that the set
$$
\{x\in [0,1] \mid x \text{ is a Lebesgue point and } f(x) \in A \},
$$
is of full measure.

My attempt: since $f\in L^1([0,1],\mathbb{R}^d)$, then almost every point $x\in [0,1]$ is a Lebesgue point of $f$. Moreover, since $f(x) \in A$ for almost every $x\in [0,1]$ so the statement should be true (since we have two negligible sets).

Another question that has been puzzling me is why we can't write $f(x)$ for all $t\in [0,1]$ (we can only speak of $f(x)$ only if $x$ is a Lebesgue point). Does it mean it can be equal to infinity at certain points?

About Lebesgue points: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue_point

Comment: Your attempt is the complete answer to the first question. Why do you doubt yourself?

Comment: Second question: You can change the value **arbitrarily** at points other the Lebesgue points wihtout changing $f$ as an element of $L^{\infty}$.